# Error on import math when embedding python in C

Tags: python, c, macos, module, importerror

I would like to embed python into a C application.  Specifically, I would like to use sympy as part of the python portion.  To accomplish this I created a clean install of anaconda.  Here is a minimal working example that illustrates my problem.

```
int main()
{
    putenv("PYTHONHOME=../anaconda3/bin/python3.7m");
    Py_SetPath(L"../:../anaconda3/lib/python3.7:../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages:../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa:../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions:../.ipython");
    Py_Initialize();

    //PyRun_SimpleString("import math\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sympy\n");

    Py_FinalizeEx();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS)
```

}

This code compiles fine, but when I attempt to run it I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import mpmath
  File "../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ctx_fp import FPContext
  File "../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/ctx_fp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ctx_base import StandardBaseContext
  File "../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/ctx_base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .libmp.backend import xrange
  File "../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/libmp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .libmpf import (prec_to_dps, dps_to_prec, repr_dps,
  File "../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpmath/libmp/libmpf.py", line 7, in <module>
    import math
ImportError: dlopen(../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyExc_MemoryError
  Referenced from: ../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Looking at this error it appears that there is an error on "import math".  Importing math by itself gives the following error confirming this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyExc_MemoryError
  Referenced from: ../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

I found several references where similar problems were encountered and discussed (e.g. [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6401), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745053/embeded-python-import-math-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444975/can-not-import-packages-in-python-when-embedding-python-in-c), and [this](https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/21)), but the solutions have either not worked, weren't provided, or I didn't fully understand how they might relate to my problem.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842920/undefined-symbol-pyexc-importerror-when-embedding-python-in-c) solution suggested adding the following line before initialize may help

```
void*const libpython_handle = dlopen("libpython3.7m.dylib", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);  // update to my python version
```

I also tried

```
void*const libpython_handle = dlopen("../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

as this specifically is (apparently) what's causing the problem.  Neither worked.  It appears that the problem is related to dependency problems with lib-dynload/* files (discussed [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/new-bugs-announce/2008-November/003322.html)), but thus far I have not been able to find a workaround.

How might I fix this problem?

Edit:

I am using MacOS

Comment: I am working on the same thing.

I was able to resolve this specific issue by adding `-framework Python` to my `gcc` command.

However this gives me another "Symbol not found" error but this time on `__Py_FalseStruct`.

If you have this working on your end I would love to hear how you solved it!